# How to list all topics created by me

Tags: twiki, foswiki

How can I get a list of all topics that I created?

I think it should be something like

```
%SEARCH{ "versions[-1].info.author = '%USERNAME%" type="query" web="Sandbox" }%
```

but that returns 0 results.

With `"versions[-1]"` I get all topics, and with `"info.author = '%USERNAME%'"` a list of the topics where the last edit was made by me. Having a list of all topics where *any* edit was made by me would be fine, too, but `"versions.info.author = '%USERNAME%'"` again gives 0 results.

I’m using Foswiki-1.0.9. (I know that’s quite old.)

Answer (score 2):

The right syntax would be

```
%SEARCH{ "versions[-1,info.author='%USERNAME%']" type="query" web="Sandbox"}%
```

But that's not performing well, i.e. on your old Foswiki install.

Better is to install DBCacheContrib and DBCachePlugin and use

```
%DBQUERY{"createauthor='%WIKINAME%'"}%
```

This plugin caches the initial author in a way it does not have to retrieve the information from the revision system for every topic under consideration during query time.

Comment: With the syntax you proposed, I get an `Could not perform search. Error was: Syntax error in 'versions[-1,info.author='MyUserName']' at ',info.author='MyUserName']'` (Foswiki version too old?). And unfortunately, we don’t have DBCacheContrib and DBCachePlugin installed, but I’ll ask whether it might be possible to install them.

Comment: According to foswiki.org, `versions[-1,info.author='RoaldDahl']` [selects all versions that are authored by 'RoaldDahl' and also selects the oldest revision](http://foswiki.org/System/QuerySearch), which is not what I'm looking for.